# Why browser stops for a while loading web page resources?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I am testing a website on gtmetrix (https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.winni.in/Wvpln9Q6) and in reports generated by gtmetrix I always see few lags, during which no resource loads and after some milliseconds it starts again. Please check report in above link, I have also attached image below for that report for better understanding

[image]

Here after html page load, it halts for about 250ms and then it starts loading css file. After fetching few files it stops for a while after fetching `init.min.js`. After that it starts again and stops for a while again after loading `analytics.js`.

Due to this, overall page load time increases a lot. Which otherwise would be less if it does not halt while fetching files.

Questions are:

1. Why does it happen like this? I have not seen like this on other websites
2. What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screen shot I thinks what is slowing your loading I think it is the Fonts woff file.

Read this article about fonts optimization from Google
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/webfont-optimization

Comment: I thought about it, but it takes time before fetching `main.min.css` and after that `fstar.png`. Fonts come after that, before fonts it already took two lags